# Angular form pattern validation producing false positives

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, forms

I'm trying to create a IP address validation on simple text input field but i get strange false positive.

My test html file looks like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="ipValid" [pattern]="ipRegex" />
    <span *ngIf="form.hasError('pattern', ['ipValid'])">Pattern error</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="ipInvalid" [pattern]="ipRegex" />
    <span *ngIf="form.hasError('pattern', ['ipInvalid'])">Pattern error</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="ipWrongValid" [pattern]="ipRegex" />
    <span *ngIf="form.hasError('pattern', ['ipWrongValid'])">Pattern error</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

And simple typescript component:

```js
export class App {
  ipRegex = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9]))?$';

  form = new FormGroup({
    ipValid: new FormControl('1.1.1.1'),
    ipInvalid: new FormControl('1...'),
    ipWrongValid: new FormControl('123.123'),
  });
}
```

Working code example is bellow can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hiyxvh?file=src/main.ts

I got the IP Address regex from one of the stackoverflow posts and i also tested that regex with some online regex tester and it seemed to work.

Now i get correct result for `1.1.1.1` (valid) and `1...` (invalid) but i get a false positive for `123.123` which is not a correct IP address format.

My question is what did i do wrong or where did i miss something?

Since i dont know how internals of angular forms pattern validation works but i noticed that for some reason `new RegExp()` can also produce similar false positive.

Here is the example with the same regex using `RegExp`:

```js
const str = '123.123';

const regex = new RegExp('^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9]))?$');

console.log(regex.test(str)); 
// returns true
```

But if i run the same regex with regex test function i get correct answer:

```js
const str = '123.123';

/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9]))?$/.test(str);
// returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex matchers in provided snippet and stackblitz link are different. Latter lacks escaping `\` before dots and slashes.

As a result `123.123` matches as:

- `1` - first group,
- `2` - `.` (any symbol) between first and second group,
- `3` - second group,
- `.` - `.` between second and third group,
- `1` - third group,
- `2` - `.` between third and forth group,
- `3` - forth group.

Comment: Maybe stackblitz didnt update but i made sure that i tested with same regex in all three examples. Anyway your answer was helpful, it made me try to change regex input from literal string to regex format which worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With help of markalex answer i tried to change regex input from literal string to regex format and it worked!

So i changed this:

```js
export class App {
  ipRegex = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9]))?$';

  form = new FormGroup({
    ipValid: new FormControl('1.1.1.1'),
    ipInvalid: new FormControl('1...'),
    ipWrongValid: new FormControl('123.123'),
  });
}
```

To this:

```js
export class App {
  ipRegex = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])(\/([1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|[0-9]))?$/;

  form = new FormGroup({
    ipValid: new FormControl('1.1.1.1'),
    ipInvalid: new FormControl('1...'),
    ipWrongValid: new FormControl('123.123'),
  });
}
```

Note that `ipRegex` does not start and end with `'` but with `/`.

This solved my issue.